# how to use type annotation for computed state in pinia and vue3 with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typeerror, pinia

I have a definition in my Pinia store.

```js
// "use strict";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ComputedRef, computed, reactive, ref } from "vue";


export const useRCUStore = defineStore("rcu", () => {
  const current_setting = computed(() => {
    let regs = Buffer.from(modbus.regs_holding);
    return regs.readUInt16BE(14 * 2) / 128;
  });

  const io_enable = computed(() => {
    let regs = Buffer.from(modbus.regs_coil);
    return regs.readUint8(23) !== 0;
  });

  function update_current_setting(d: number) {
    console.log(`update_current_setting  ${d}`);
    modbus.queue_write(true, 14, d * 128);
  }
 
  function update_io_control_enable(d: number) {
    console.log(`update_io_control_enable  ${d}`);
    d = d > 1 ? 1 : 0;
    modbus.queue_write(false, 23, d);
  }
  const item_mapping: {
    [id: string]: { write: (d: number) => void; read: ComputedRef<number | boolean> };
  } = {
    Current_setting: { write: update_current_setting, read: current_setting },
    IO_control_enable: { write: update_io_control_enable, read: io_enable },
  };

  return {
    modbus,item_mapping,current_setting, io_enable,update_current_setting,  
  };
});
```

and I use the store in the vue component as this:

```js
const rcu = useRCUStore();

interface ConfigItem {
  label: string;
  value: number;
  oldValue: number | boolean;
}
const config_list = reactive([] as ConfigItem[]);

  let a: number | boolean = rcu.current_setting;
  let b: number | boolean = rcu.current_setting.value;
  console.info("rcu.current_setting", a, b);
  config_list.forEach((item: ConfigItem) => {
    item.oldValue = rcu.item_mapping[item.label].read;
  });
```

then I got the error `Type 'ComputedRef<number | boolean>' is not assignable to type 'number | boolean'.ts(2322)` by the vscode.

but I try to run the code and prove that `rcu.item_mapping[item.label].read` and `rcu.current_setting` is the correct value

`rcu.item_mapping[item.label].read.value` and `rcu.current_setting.value` are `undefined`.

May I know why it working like this? and how should I use the type annotation correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**TypeScript does not run in the browser**, during compilation it transpiles to JavaScript.  Type errors in TypeScript are not going to cause the resulting JavaScript to not run, because once the code is JavaScript the types and any type errors are now gone.

To correct the type error, you just need to assign the `number | boolean` [inner value](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), not the Ref itself.  This is done using `.value`

```js
item.oldValue = rcu.item_mapping[item.label].read.value;
```

Comment: like I mention in the question description. `rcu.item_mapping[item.label].read.value` is `undefined`.  `rcu.item_mapping[item.label].read` can get the correct value.